# Hiding mouseover tooltip in charts

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I would like to know how can I make it so that a chart doesn't show the data point value on hover.
The chart in question plots a range with formulas so I can toggle all the series, and I need the solution to be on the file so that no one can see the actual values under the chart.

Comment: The thing about the "Show data points" option is that it affects the application, not the file. Any computer that opens the file will have to do the same thing.